# How fix HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR on several columns in athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, amazon-athena

I am trying to execute the following select statement in aws athena:

```
SELECT
    col_1,
    col_2
FROM "my_database"."my_table"
WHERE
        partition_1='20171130'
    AND
        partition_2='Y'
LIMIT 10
```

And I got en error:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Can not read value at 0 in block 0 in file s3://my-s3-path/my-table/partition_1=20171130/partition_2=Y/part-1111-11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.snappy.parquet

This query ran against the "my_database" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 1111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.
```

But when I **remove just one** of column it works! E.g. selects with 1 column works:

- `SELECT col_1 FROM "my_database"."my_table" WHERE partition_1='20171130' AND partition_2='Y' LIMIT 10`
- `SELECT col_2 FROM "my_database"."my_table" WHERE partition_1='20171130' AND partition_2='Y' LIMIT 10`

Also I spot I *can* add more than 1 column to select statement, but it fails just with some combinations. But why?
Table definition is:

```
{
  "Table": {
    "StorageDescriptor": {
      "OutputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat",
      "SortColumns": [],
      "InputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat",
      "SerdeInfo": {
        "SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe",
        "Parameters": {
          "serialization.format": "1"
        }
      },
      "BucketColumns": [],
      "Parameters": {
        "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
        "compressionType": "none",
        "UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER": "myCrawler",
        "classification": "parquet",
        "recordCount": "40190451",
        "typeOfData": "file",
        "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
        "objectCount": "18",
        "averageRecordSize": "35",
        "exclusions": "[\"s3://my-s3-path/my_table/_**\"]",
        "sizeKey": "1078884110"
      },
      "Location": "s3://my-s3-path/my-table/",
      "NumberOfBuckets": -1,
      "StoredAsSubDirectories": false,
      "Columns": [
        {
          "Type": "smallint",
          "Name": "col_1"
        },
        {
          "Type": "decimal(18,6)",
          "Name": "col_2"
        }
      ],
      "Compressed": false
    },
    "UpdateTime": 1515503623.0,
    "PartitionKeys": [
      {
        "Type": "string",
        "Name": "partition_1"
      },
      {
        "Type": "string",
        "Name": "partition_2"
      }
    ],
    "Name": "my_table",
    "Parameters": {
      "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
      "compressionType": "none",
      "UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER": "myCrawler",
      "classification": "parquet",
      "recordCount": "40190451",
      "typeOfData": "file",
      "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
      "objectCount": "18",
      "averageRecordSize": "35",
      "exclusions": "[\"s3://my-s3-path/my_table/_**\"]",
      "sizeKey": "1078884110"
    },
    "LastAccessTime": 1515503623.0,
    "CreatedBy": "arn:aws:sts::111111111111:assumed-role/MyRole/myCrawler",
    "TableType": "EXTERNAL_TABLE",
    "Owner": "owner",
    "CreateTime": 1515503623.0,
    "Retention": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the schema using parquet-tools and see if it is matching with the table definition? https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools

Answer (score 1):

Typically this error is due to a mismatch in the schemas or data in the files. For parquet make sure that the file's schema matches the Hive schema *exactly*. Even the order of the columns matters at times, structs for example.

Also, sparse fields are sometimes dropped by parquet writers if the output file rows do not include any data for the column. This is common in situations where you are partitioning.

Comment: Also, I've hit silly things like having an extra space after the types when defining a map<>, capitalizing the data type or putting `int` instead of `integer`. Athena is really specific in its table definitions.

Comment: The main question is... why doesn't Athena do better error messages :D